# show first few obs used in lm statement

Tags: r, lm

let's say I have a formula (e.g., `myformula <- y ~ x1 + x2`) and a dataset d.  for diagnostic purposes, I would like to see what the observations are that end up being used in my linear regression (`r <- lm(myformula, data=d)`).  this basically entails building a dataframe with y, x1, and x2 according to d and removing all observations that have any missing data (complete.obs).  or, perhaps, manipulating the contents of the r object?

advice appreciated.

/iaw

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before trying to roll your own, have a look at the model object (use `str(r)` to get a peak at what's there) or look for relevant bits in the documentation. From `?lm`:

> `model, x, y, qr`
>   logicals. If `TRUE` the corresponding components of the fit (the model frame, the model matrix, the response, the QR decomposition) are returned.

Since `model` is true by default, all we have to do is look for it in the result. The **Value** section of the documentation describes the object returned:

> `y` if requested, the response used.
>
> `x` if requested, the model matrix used.
>
> `model` if requested (the default), the model frame used.

Now an example:

```
> mod = lm(mpg ~ disp + I(disp^2), data = mtcars)
> head(mod$model)
                   mpg disp I(disp^2)
Mazda RX4         21.0  160     25600
Mazda RX4 Wag     21.0  160     25600
Datsun 710        22.8  108     11664
Hornet 4 Drive    21.4  258     66564
Hornet Sportabout 18.7  360    129600
Valiant           18.1  225     50625
```

Note that this is strictly data and is still a `data.frame`. if you want the *model matrix*, a `matrix` with dummy variables for the intercept and any factors, set `x = TRUE` in the `lm` call and then look at `mod$x`.